# Ring Homomorpism

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the polynomial ring $R[X]$ and the ring $M_2(R)$ of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in R. We define a map $t: R[X] \to M_2(R)$ by

$$t(f) = \begin{pmatrix}f(0)&  f'(0)\\0 &  f(0)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $f'$ denotes usual derivative of $f$.

Show that t is a homomorphism. Determine the kernel and the image of t. Is ker(t) a principal ideal.

I have shown that t is a homomorphism, however am stuck on the rest of the question. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: $f\in\ker t$ if and only if $t(f)=0$, that is...; as for the image, can you try with $f=a+bX$? What's $t(f)$? What triangular matrices do you obtain?

Comment: Which $f$ satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$? If I wanted to have the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$ which $f$ would I choose? If I wanted to have the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which $f$ would I choose? Finally, note that if $R$ is a field, then $R[X]$ is a Euclidean domain, and so a P.I.D. The kernel is always an ideal and so must be principal.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\ker T=\{f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\;;\;f(0)=f'(0)=0\iff x^n\mid f(x)\;,\;\;2\le n\in\Bbb N\}\;\ldots$$

Check now that

$$\forall\;\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\Bbb R)\;\;\exists\,f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\;\;s.t.\,\,f(0)=a\;,\;f'(0)=b$$

Comment: OK, whatever. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ $ in $\,S = R[x]/(x^2)\,$ the linear map $\, g\to fg = (a+bx)g\,$ satisfies

$$\begin{eqnarray} (a+bx) 1 &=\,& a + bx \\ (a+bx) x &=\,& 0 + ax\end{eqnarray}$$

hence its matrix in the basis $\, \langle1,x\rangle\,$ is

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & a\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} f(0) &\!\! f'(0)\\ 0 &\!\! f(0)\end{array}\right] $$